# Image map (html img usemap) in Outlook signature created by VBS script?

Tags: html, vbscript, outlook

I know it is recommended not to use image maps in emails, but that aside, how can I (or can I) create an image with a usemap tag in Outlook using VBS?

My current piece of code for inserting the logo and link is:

```
'insert campaign banner
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strCampaignBannerLoc), strCampaignURL,,,"")
```

This month's campaign image is a rectangle showing three events, I want a link for each event and I would like to avoid three images.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a raw text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup which represents the body.
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body. So, you can use the Word object model to custimize the body.

You can read more about all of these way in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article in MSDN.